# How to check if a certain part of an input is in a list of possible inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find the exact answer or a close-enough in other questions.

I want to make a program that checks if any part of a users input is matching to another possible input in a list. And if part of that input was something in a list, that part of the input could be saved as another variable.

```
correct = ["game","code","text"]
command = input("> ")
if command == "open" + something in correct:
    name = thing in correct
    doSomething()
```

So if the command was 'open text', then name would be 'text'.

Is this even possible? Again, sorry if this has already been asked, and sorry if this is rambling and makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumning you expect the command and its parameters to be separated by a space (or multiple spaces for multiple parameters), you could do this:

```
correct = ["game","code","text"]
command = input("> ")
subcommands = command.split(" ")

if subcommands[0] == "open" and subcommands[1] in correct:
    name = subcommands[1]
    doSomething()
```

This gets more tricky if parameters are supposed to contain spaces themselves, but for simple one-word params, this should do.

Comment: This is just what I'm looking for! Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear this solves it - can you please mark it as answer then.